# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code while testing Flutter App in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am trying to test my Flutter App on my iPhone but every time i try to run it i in XCode get the error message: *Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code*

I tried a lot of things.

1. desintegrate and integrate pods
2. Lock and unlock keychain access
3. To run the embededded Pods Framework only while instaling
   4 And yes there is no space in my project directory

Is there any other solution?
Thangs for any answer.

**Error Message:**

[image: Error Message: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code]

Answer (score 1):

try this way!

1. delete .symlinks
2. delete pods directory
3. delete podfile.lock file

and reinstall the pods. and run it on x-code

Comment: How do i delete .symlinks?

Comment: when you install pods you can see in your IOS folder it automatically generate .symlinks folder project/IOS/.symlinks

Comment: i tryed your solution and deleted the .symlink file but nothing happend

Answer (score 1):

You can try deleting the derived data in Xcode and then delete podfile.lock and install the podfile again. If the error persist you can share the screenshot of error.

Comment: I edited my question to include the error message, but nothing changed.

Comment: when you will click on error message then a file will opened. Can you share that file's screenshot. Because error details are in that file.